# Angular + Typescript + JSPM (ES6 Modules) -> WallabyJS Configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jspm

I'm trying to configure WallabyJs to work with JSPM and Typescript
I tried following a [few](https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallaby-jspm-sample) [examples](https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallaby-typescript-angular-seed) found on Wallaby's Github account but couldn't make my setup work.

I want to be able to write my tests using TS and ES6 Modules

---

Here's my sample SpecFile:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import * as ng from 'angular';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    console.log(ng);

  });
});
```

### [Here's my current `wallaby.js` configuration](http://pastebin.com/5q8WZrZA)

Note that it is based on a few different samples I found around and is pretty much all over the place

With this config, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
>       at jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular-mocks@1.4.7.js:1
>
> TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call.
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:4
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>
> Error: Module http://localhost:55533/app/src/app.spec.js interpreted as global module format, but called System.register.
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:4
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:4
>       at jspm_packages/system.js:5

---

### If I change the `module: 4` to `module: 1` in the compiler configuration, I get:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
>       at jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular-mocks@1.4.7.js:1
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
>       at app/src/app.spec.ts:3

Comment: You should open an issue about it [in the wallabyjs repo](https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues).

Comment: Yes that was the next step, thank you

Comment: `instrument: true` and `load: true` are defaults, so you could omit these file pattern params

Comment: Answered [in the wallaby.js repo](https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/325#issuecomment-155274711)